# MySQL query works in query window, but didn't work in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not php developer, I'm Android/Java developer, and I need some help in php coding. I need to get some objects from mysql with php. When I'm sending query to mysql with php, it's returns null.. but the same code is working in query window. here is my query..

```
SELECT id, title, latitude, longitude FROM google_map_table WHERE title = 'Café Chiquito'
```

also, when I'm getting object with id(int), it's work in php.. but didn't work when I'm searching with title(not int). Can someone help me to get object with title in php?
Thanks in advance...

here is whole code..

```
$map_result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, latitude, longitude FROM google_map_table WHERE title = '`Café Chiquito`'") or die(mysql_error());

$map_row = mysql_fetch_array($map_result);

$collector = array();
$collector["title"] = $map_row["title"];
$collector["latitude"] = $map_row["latitude"];
$collector["longitude"] = $map_row["longitude"];

echo json_encode($collector);
```

it's prints null.. but when I'm searching object with id, it's work.. like this

```
"SELECT id, title, latitude, longitude FROM google_map_table WHERE id = 1"
```

Comment: Rather than the query show how you use it in PHP. There is nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: probably that `é` getting mangled somewhere in the pipeline. You have to maintain the **SAME** character set through out the entire process, or at least connect the stages with appropriate charset conversion logic. Otherwise you'll end up with mangled chars and strings that will never match.

Comment: What does your PHP look like for the query?

Comment: Marc B.. that é is working in mysql query window..

Comment: so, don't downrate.. if you don't know answer..

Comment: @Henrik And... it probably doesn't work in PHP. Marc is probably right.

Comment: best way you can go to solve this is check the `mysql.log` to see the exact query you are submiting from PHP, I bet it isn't the same one as you are using in the query window.

Comment: @henrik: doesn't mean anything. you need to ensure that the php->mysql->table->mysql->php pipeline is completely uniform for charset, e.g. utf-8 all the way. if a single stage is a DIFFERENT charset, you'll get mangled text.

Comment: thanks for all comments.. I'll try..

Answer (score 0):

If you receive the title through `$_POST` you probably have to `utf8_decode()`, depending on your web server configuration. It has to be some problem with the charset.

If you want to know the exact query your Mysql is receiving check the mysql.log. Doing a `echo` of the query will not help if you have a problem with the charset.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
$map_result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, latitude, longitude FROM google_map_table WHERE title = 'Café Chiquito'") or die(mysql_error());
```

escape character '`' in title value might cause the issue here.